# How to Avoid multiple Joins for extracting a specific information

Tags: sql

For the following sql table

```
Row   Year Month Reason
1     FY22  Apr  SLA missed due to xyz reason
2     FY22  May  SLA missed due to xyz reason
3     FY22  June SLA missed due to xyz reason
4     FY22  July SLA missed due to ABC reason
5     FY22  Aug  SLA missed due to ABC reason
6     FY22  Sep  SLA missed due to ABC reason
7     FY22  Oct  SLA missed due to PQR reason
8     FY22  Nov  SLA missed due to PQR reason
9     FY22  Dec  SLA missed due to PQR reason
```

Is it possible to get this output (I'm trying with multiple left joins but is there any easy way?)

Output expected is

```
Row 1 - " Apr-Jun: 'SLA missed due to xyz reason' "
        " Jul-Aug: 'SLA missed due to ABC reason' "
        " Oct-Dec: 'SLA missed due to PQR reason' "
Row 2 -
```

Comment: Please tag which database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

you can use GROUP BY and concatenate strings Column

If it is SQL Server 2017 or SQL Server Vnext, SQL Azure you can use string_agg as below:

```
select '" '+string_agg(concat(Month, ':', [Month]), '- ')+':'''+Reason+''' "'
from table
group by Reason
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gap-and-islands problem.  You can get the individual reasons on a single row using the difference of row numbers.  Now, let me assume that the dates follow the ordering of `row` -- or that you at least have a column that clearly defines the order (FY and month are difficult to work with).

Then:

```
select reason,
       min(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then year end) as start_year,
       min(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then month end) as start_month,
       min(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then year end) as end_year,
       min(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then month end) as end_month,
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by reason, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by rowid) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by reason, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by rowid) as seqnum_desc
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by reason order by row) as seqnum_2,
                   row_number() over (order by row) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by reason, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

To get the result that you actually specify, you would need to use one more level of aggregation, using strings.  However, that syntax varies significantly by database, so perhaps this is sufficient to answer your question.